# To call a batch file from powershell (where the batch file calls an .exe)

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to call a batch script from powershell.
I'm using the command Start-Process

`Start-Process D:\Homeware\install.bat -wait`

The batch file calls an .exe file.

My problem is Start-Process works fine the batch file is called, whereas the .exe file is not triggered.

Content of install.bat
`..\InstallVersion\InstallVersion.exe`

Comment: Use an absolute path to load your executable in the batch file to see if that makes a difference. You can also use echo commands for debugging.

Comment: If the only content of the batch file is the line to call the exe, why not start the exe from PowerShell? (partially loaded question here) If the bat file has more in it, perhaps showing more details would help clarify your question so people on SO can help you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Start-Process` by default starts the new process in the same directory as the calling PowerShell instance's working directory.

Thus, you can't just use a *relative* path to your `.exe` file in your batch file.

If the path is meant to be relative to the *batch file's* location, invoke the `.exe` as follows from your batch file:

```
"%~dp0..\InstallVersion\InstallVersion.exe"
```

`%0` contains the file path of the batch file itself, and modifiers `~dp` extract the drive (`d`) and directory path (`p`, including trailing `\`) portions from that path.

---

If you cannot edit the batch file, simply ensure that the working directory is set to the directory in which the batch file is located, using `Start-Process`' `-WorkingDirectory` parameter:

```
Start-Process D:\Homeware\install.bat -wait -WorkingDirectory D:\Homeware
```

Comment: Thanks mklement0 is there anyway I can do it without editing the .bat file. Your answer worked, I'm able to call the batch file now