# Calling 2 variables

Tags: windows, powershell

My question is in regards to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051355/to-call-a-batch-file-from-powershell-where-the-batch-file-calls-an-exe).

I got the solution for my previous question but when I pass my value in variable it is not working.
The `Start-Process` is not able to trigger the batch file. I assume that it doesn't recognize the variable `"$Gros"`.

```
$version = Read-Host - Prompt 'Enter the version to copy'
$Gros="D:\homeware\Gros\$version"
Start-Process $Gros\install.bat -wait -WorkingDirectory "$Gros"
```

Error:

```
Start-Process : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter
name 'WorkingDirectory "$Gros"'.
At D:\homeware\Scripts\OMS_deploy.ps1:66 char:64
+ Start-Process $Gros\install.bat -wait -WorkingDirectory "$Gros" <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Comment: Are you sure that space between `-WorkingDirectory` and `"$Gros"` is normal? I can reproduce that error message when I put `U+00A0` (*No-Break Space*) instead of normal one.

Comment: Yes the space is necessary, It works fine in command line. Only when I execute as a script it doesn't work.

Comment: @samjerry That wasn't the question. Is the space between `-WorkingDirectory` and `"$Gros"` a **regular** space (ASCII character 0x40), or is it some other whitespace character, like a non-breaking space (Unicode character U+00A0), as PetSerAl suspected? The error message clearly says that PowerShell interprets the entire string `-WorkingDirectory "$Gros"` as one parameter name, not as a parameter with its argument.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get the question properly. You guys were right. It was due to Non-Break Space. Thank you PetSerAl and Ansgar Wiechers, appreciate your response

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Start-Process $Gros\install.bat -WorkingDirectory $Gros -wait
```

Comment: Thanks Dewi Jones, my syntax was right it was just about the space.